# Beamer index showing too many titles with overlays

Tags: beamer, overlays, themes

I'm trying to create my first presentation with the `beamer` class. I saw that is possible to change the color (for example) of a part of text with overlays. I'm using `{\alert{<...>}{text}}` to highlight some constants inside a formula, and I noticed some issues:

- To have the frame title in the index on the right (for the `Goettingen` theme) I have to insert a `\section{...}` with the same title. Is it correct? Because this section seems "useless" to me, since there is already the frame title (however, if this is the case, I'll stick with it).
- When I use `{\alert{<2->}{text}}` it produce another slide inside the frame; this is fine, since it works in the presentation. However, this command creates **another title** in the index on the right, and this will be shown even in the presentation. Is there a way to have only one item per, let's say, frame in the index created by the theme?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny

\usetheme{Goettingen}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First frame}
    \section{First frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \[{\alpha = \alert<2->{k_1}}\]
        \item Item 2
        \[{\alpha = \alert<2->{k_2}}\]
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Second frame}
    \section{Second frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \[{\alpha = \alert<2->{k_1}}\]
        \item Item 2
        \[{\alpha = \alert<2->{k_2}}\]
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: The sidebar is intended to show sections and subsections, not every frame. To make a book analogy, frames are the paragraphs and figures that comprise (sub)sections. The TOC only shows these (sub)sections, not every page. Themes with a TOC sidebar are good for long presentations and lectures, but other themes would be better for shorter talks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue mentioned in 2), the problem with your code is that you are issuing `\section` inside a `frame` environment. `\section` (and all other sectional unit commands) must be *outside* `frame`; a section is composed by several frames, but it has no sense to put a section inside a frame (besides, this has unwanted results like the one you describe):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny

\usetheme{Goettingen}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{First frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{First frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \[{\alpha = \alert<2->{k_1}}\]
        \item Item 2
        \[{\alpha = \alert<3->{k_2}}\]
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Second frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Second frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \[{\alpha = \alert<2->{k_1}}\]
        \item Item 2
        \[{\alpha = \alert<2->{k_2}}\]
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

An animation of the result showing just the two sections in the sidebar:

[image]

Regarding 1), The sidebar (and, in general, the navigation bar) is meant to have the information about major sectional units (sections and subsections), but not the title for every frame (this wouldn't make much sense).

Comment: Thank you, I thought that I had to put everything inside a frame. Unfortunately I didn't have enough time to carefully read a manual, but I will :-) ! Thanks again!